# This CodeIgniter URL is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a link,

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo base_url(); ?>
    <p><a href="news/view/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>"> View article </a></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This is the code from the user guide od CodeIgniter. Clicking on the link of this code, it says:

> The requested URL was not found

Why?

The link formed is `http://localhost/codeignitor/news/view/20`.

This is my controller:-

```
<?php
    class news extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
                    $this->load->helper("url");
            $this->load->model('news_model');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
                    $data['title'] = ' News archive ';

                    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
                    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function view($slug)
        {
            $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
            if (empty($data['news_item']))
            {
                show_404();
            }
            $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is code, not link. Show us live example or generated HTML.

Comment: codeignitor/news/view/20  is the link , is it correct formed

Comment: What not working means ? How is your class/controller ? Do you have any mapping ? Post the `class/controller` you want to map to.

Comment: see i have a class named "news" and it has a function "view" which contains one parameter , now you can figure, is the link correct or not?

Comment: change `<a href="news/view/` to `<a href="view/`... i have had this problem with that tutorial before.

Comment: you do remember that "news" is my controller that i have to call compulsory

Comment: You must uppercase news in the class definition. So .... class News extends CI_Controller. That should be one problem (maybe), then the solution y gave to you should be correct.

Comment: the real problem is with the .htaccess file, i am not getting the write htaccess code , can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You're only giving the controller and method path. You're missing your page's URL:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('news/view/'.$news_item['slug']);?>"> View article </a>
```

Check the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the base URL function properly:

```
base_url('news/view/'.$news_item['slug']);
```

Comment: base_url will not work because it gives you your site base URL without the index_page or url_suffix being appended